# Set IP address inside JTextField in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, ip, jtextfield

I have this simple GUI in JAVA and i want to put inside the JTextField a string
that contains the IP of my local machine.

I tried to get the IP with this command :

`InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();`

and to store it inside a string , and to put the string inside the JTextField
I have tried using `gettext()` and `settext()`, but without success.

The code :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class GuiLearn extends JFrame {
    private JLabel label;
    private JTextField textfield;

    public GuiLearn () {
        setLayout (new FlowLayout());

        textfield = new JTextField("This is where the IP address should be...");
        add(textfield);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        GuiLearn yuvi = new GuiLearn();

        yuvi.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        yuvi.setSize(400,400);
        yuvi.setVisible(true);
        yuvi.setTitle("guiiiiiii");
    }
}
```

please help..

Comment: What do you mean "without success"? What happened instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate your JTextField, the String argument you pass into the constructor will set the text for you. 
Since `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` returns a String, you can simply pass it in as a constructor argument to the JTextField.

```
this.textfield = new JTextField(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
```

Or you can simply call `this.textField.setText(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress())` at any point after you have instantiated the object.